# Проблема кодировки при загрузке дапма на другой сервер

Tags: mysql, sql, кодировка, phpmyadmin

Сделан дамп через Navicat Premium, кодировка в UTF-8 ( Говорят что базу нужно держать в win-1251? ). 
Загружаю этот дамп через ISPmanager, грузиться нормально, когда зашел на PhpMyAdmin, там русские буквы все такого вида (ÐœÐ¾Ð¸ Ð»Ð). 
Менял в настройках PhpMyAdmin кодировку на UTF-8 и при загрузке на панели тоже было в UTF-8, сам файл sql тоже в кодировке UTF-8. Не могу понять, можете помочь?

Comment: Вы почему-то вместо win1251 пишете win1501, русские буквы "побились" именно в направлении cp2151 -> UFT8 (декодер подсказывает, что ваши буквы "ÐœÐ¾Ð¸ Ð»Ð" = "Мои л").

Comment: Внутри дампа есть команда SET NAMES utf8? В оригинальной базе данных таблицы в Windows-1251?

Comment: В UTF-8, да извините перепутал, 1251.

Comment: Пробовал менять на win 1251, все ровно не работает, в заместо кривизны выводятся вопросы.

Comment: С вин 1251 выводит вопросы. Не знаю что за фигня(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашел в инете, спустя часы поисков.
Перед этим настроил max загрузку файлов и через SSH:

```
mysql -h hostname -u user-name -default_character_set utf8 -p DB_name <  /path-to-dir/dump.sql
```